# Define configuration file that not need to be compile

Tags: android

i am programming an android application, and i would like to know if there is a way to create a configuration file that  can be change, while the changes will take effect on the application without the need to compile it again?

does store it in external storage is the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can use json file or xml file and write a configuration to file. 
File can be keep in /sdcard/

Comment: where i can find it in the project folder? for example i would like to change the URL of the server inside this file and after i compile it the URL will updated on the emulator.

Comment: you asked about change configuration without compile. /sdcard/ is a dir outside the project. it is a public dir. 
You can update configuration of your application when application is started

Comment: OK thanks, other question if i will run it on my personal device what will be the effect? because i don't have any sdcard on my phone.

Comment: This is not a problem for android. If you don't have sdcard inside phone - most of androids devices has a virtual folder: /sdcard where you can put files